# Can I, without damaging the carpet, align this threshold properly by prying it from the floor and reapplying it?

Tags: doors, threshold

The contractor who put in the carpet in this room did not align the threshold properly with the door frame. I recently had a French door put in, and now this misalignment is more noticeable. What is the proper way to pry this up and nail back down so it is aligned? Is it possible? Is it just as simple as putting a trim crow bar underneath, getting it all up, and then just hammering back down, or will that damage the threshold?

[image: Carpet threshold]

Comment: Do you mean the carpet termination strip? I don't see anything I'd call a threshold. Maybe add a  photo that's not so flat in perspective. Be sure it's lit well enough for us to see clearly.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a metal termination strip, it has been pinched down onto the carpet by hammering. You'd need to flex it up, pull back the carpet, then reposition it. You'll need to trim the carpet to fit (or stretch it a bit) and then pound it back down.

I suppose it's possible that you could pry it loose, work the nails through the carpet to remove them, and then drive nails through the carpet to reposition it. That would require stretching the carpet, too. It's not really the right way to do this job.

I'd probably plan on just replacing the strip. It's not expensive, and the likelihood that you'll bend it up a bit removing it is fairly high.

Answer (score 1):

When I zoom in, it looks like this to me (courtesy of alibaba)

[image]

You will notice the backward-pointing hooks.  The carpet is stretched with a carpet stretcher or a knee-kicker and snagged on these hooks.  Then the top portion is gently hammered down.

It is not going to be easy to fix it without looking like it's been bashed.  And you won't have a carpet stretcher.

On the other hand, the pile is drooping over the trim.  If it's just the pile making it look messy, then you can't do much about it.

Comment: Carpet stretchers *can* be rented from Home Depot, and probably other tool rental joints...